# JavaScript encoding with Special characters

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8

I wanted to write a method to escape special chars like 'ä' to their responding Unicode (e.g. \u00e4).

For some reason JS finds it amusing to not even save the 'ä' internally but use 'Ã¼Ãœ' or some other garble, so when I convert it spits out '\u00c3\u00b6\u00c3\u002013' because it converts these chars instead of 'ä'.

I have tried setting the HTML file's encoding to utf-8 and tried loading the scripts with charset="UTF-8" to no avail. The code doesn't really do anything special but here it is:

```
String.prototype.replaceWithUtf8 = function() {
    var str_newString = '';
    var str_procString = this;

    for (var i = 0; i < str_procString.length; i++) {
        if (str_procString.charCodeAt(i) > 126) {
            var hex_uniCode = '\\u00' + str_procString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16);
            console.log(hex_uniCode + " (" + str_procString.charAt(i) + ")");
            str_newString += hex_uniCode;
        } else {
            str_newString += str_procString.charAt(i);
        }
    }
    return str_newString;
}
var str_item = "Lärm, Lichter, Lücken, Löcher."

console.log(str_item); // LÃ¤rm, Lichter, LÃ¼cken, LÃ¶cher. 
console.log(str_item.replaceWithUtf8()); //L\u00c3\u00a4rm, Lichter, L\u00c3\u00bccken, L\u00c3\u00b6cher.
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine (http://jsfiddle.net/4HmgN/). How did you set the encoding on the HTML?

Comment: Hey @mihai, I set it like so in the head-tag:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: @mihai and like so in the script tags:
`<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="script/utf8.js"></script>`

Comment: sounds good...I'm still getting correct results in Chrome/WinXP

Comment: @mihai thanks for trying. I feel trolled by technology ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `'\\u' + ('000' + str_procString.charCodeAt(i).toString(16) ).stubstr(-4);` instead to get the right escape sequences - yours do always start with `00`. Also, instead of a for-loop processing your string, `.replace()` might be faster.

On your question:

```
console.log("Lärm, Lichter, Lücken, Löcher."); // LÃ¤rm, Lichter, LÃ¼cken, LÃ¶cher.
```

does not sound as you really sent the file with the right encoding. Might be a server problem, too, if it is correctly saved already.

Comment: I was following the escape sequences in this [table](http://www.utf8-zeichentabelle.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec) and the ones php's json_encode uses. But you make a great point with the prefixed zeros. I need to account for these correctly, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea how or why but I just restarted the server again and now it's displaying correctly. To follow up; here's the code for everyone who's interested:

```
String.prototype.replaceWithUtf8 = function() {
    var str_newString = '';
    var str_procString = this;
    var arr_replace = new Array('/', '"');
    var arr_replaceWith = new Array('\\/', '\\"');

    for (var i = 0; i < str_procString.length; i++) {
        var int_charCode = str_procString.charCodeAt(i);
        var cha_charAt = str_procString.charAt(i);
        var int_chrIndex = arr_replace.indexOf(cha_charAt);

        if (int_chrIndex > -1) {
            console.log(arr_replaceWith[int_chrIndex]);
            str_newString += arr_replaceWith[int_chrIndex];
        } else {
            if (int_charCode > 126 && int_charCode < 65536) {
                var hex_uniCode = '\\u' + ("000" + int_charCode.toString(16)).substr(-4);
                console.log(hex_uniCode + " (" + cha_charAt + ")");
                str_newString += hex_uniCode;
            } else {
                str_newString += cha_charAt;
            }
        }
    }
    return str_newString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
String.prototype.replaceWithUtf8 = function() {
  function r(r) {
    for (var t, n, e = "", i = 0; !isNaN(t = r.charCodeAt(i++)); ) n = t.toString(16), 
    e += 256 > t ? "\\x" + (t > 15 ? "" :"0") + n :"\\u" + ("0000" + n).slice(-4);
    return e;
  }
  var a, c, o, u, s, e = "", i = this, t = [ "/", '"' ], n = [ "\\/", '\\"' ];
  for (a = 0; a < i.length; a++) c = i.charCodeAt(a), o = i.charAt(a), u = t.indexOf(o), 
  u > -1 ? e += n[u] :c > 126 && 65536 > c ? (s = r(o), e += s) :e += o;
  return e;
};

prompt("Your escaped string:","Lärm, Lichter, Lücken, Löcher.".replaceWithUtf8());

alert("L\xe4rm, Lichter, L\xfccken, L\xf6cher.");
```

Unicode encoding only makes every character 6 digits. But for characters above 127 to 256, we can actually make these hexdecimal with less bytes (4 digits per character).